# Form that has either a Comic Book object or a Novel object

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Sorry if I'm double positing but I totally suck at Java.
I am trying to make my form have the ability to change dynamically if you select a radio button. The functions save, delete, new will remain the same but the contents of the body e.g. the UPC will change to ISBN of the novel and the other fields.
Is there a way to when you press Novel to load the items from Novel to replace Comic book items?
I tried to separate but I've hit a block and with my limited skills unsure what to do.
I just want it to be able to change it so that it works.

```
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormFictionCatelogue extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

// Constants
// =========
private final String FORM_TITLE = "Fiction Adiction Catelogue";
private final int X_LOC = 400;
private final int Y_LOC = 80;
private final int WIDTH = 600;
private final int HEIGHT = 450;

private String gradeCode;
//final static String filename = "data/comicBookData.txt";

private JButton firstPageButton;
private JButton backPageButton;
private JButton forwardPageButton;
private JButton lastPageButton;

private JRadioButton comicBookRadioButton;
private JRadioButton novelRadioButton;


private final String FIRSTPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT = "|<";
private final String BACKPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT = "<";
private final String FORWARDPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT = ">";
private final String LASTPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT = ">|";

private final String COMICBOOK_BUTTON_TEXT = "Comic";
private final String NOVEL_BUTTON_TEXT = "Novel";
private final String SAVE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Save";
private final String EXIT_BUTTON_TEXT = "Exit";
private final String CLEAR_BUTTON_TEXT = "Clear";
private final String FIND_BUTTON_TEXT = "Find";
private final String DELETE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Delete";
private final String ADDPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT = "New";

// Attributes
private JTextField upcTextField;
private JTextField isbnTextField;
private JTextField titleTextField;
private JTextField issueNumTextField;
private JTextField bookNumTextField;
private JTextField writerTextField;
private JTextField authorTextField;
private JTextField artistTextField;
private JTextField publisherTextField;
private JTextField seriesTextField;
private JTextField otherBooksTextField;
private JTextField gradeCodeTextField;
private JTextField charactersTextField;

private JButton saveButton;
private JButton deleteButton;
private JButton findButton;
private JButton clearButton;
private JButton exitButton;
private JButton addPageButton;

FictionCatelogue fc;

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        FormFictionCatelogue form = new FormFictionCatelogue();
        form.fc = new FictionCatelogue();
        form.setVisible(true);
        //comicBook selected by default
        form.populatefields(form.fc.returnComic(0));
        //if novel is selected change fields to novel and populate

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
* 
*/
public FormFictionCatelogue() {
    // Set form properties
    // ===================
    setTitle(FORM_TITLE);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocation(X_LOC, Y_LOC);

    // Create and set components
    // -------------------------

    // Create panels to hold components
    JPanel menuBarPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel fieldsPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel navigationPanel = new JPanel();
    //JPanel radioButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
     ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();



    // Set the layout of the panels
    GridLayout fieldsPanelLayout = new GridLayout(9, 6);

    // Menu
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("exit.png");

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

    JMenu about = new JMenu("About");
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

    JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", icon);
    eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
    eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    JMenuItem eMenuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Reports", icon);
    eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Reports are located here");
    eMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //calls reports
            //System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    file.add(eMenuItem);
    about.add(eMenuItem1);

    menubar.add(file);
    menubar.add(about);

    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    setTitle("Menu");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //if comic is selected 
    ComicBookFields(fieldsPanel);
    //else 
    //NovelFields(fieldsPanel);


    // Buttons 
    comicBookRadioButton = new JRadioButton(COMICBOOK_BUTTON_TEXT);
    novelRadioButton = new JRadioButton(NOVEL_BUTTON_TEXT);

    bG.add(comicBookRadioButton);
    bG.add(novelRadioButton);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(comicBookRadioButton);
    this.add(novelRadioButton);
    comicBookRadioButton.setSelected(true);
    bG.add(comicBookRadioButton);
    bG.add(novelRadioButton);


    addPageButton = new JButton(ADDPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    buttonsPanel.add(addPageButton);

    saveButton = new JButton(SAVE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);

    clearButton = new JButton(CLEAR_BUTTON_TEXT);
    buttonsPanel.add(clearButton);

    deleteButton = new JButton(DELETE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    buttonsPanel.add(deleteButton);

    findButton = new JButton(FIND_BUTTON_TEXT);
    buttonsPanel.add(findButton);

    exitButton = new JButton(EXIT_BUTTON_TEXT);
    buttonsPanel.add(exitButton);

    firstPageButton = new JButton(FIRSTPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    navigationPanel.add(firstPageButton);
    backPageButton = new JButton(BACKPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    navigationPanel.add(backPageButton);
    forwardPageButton = new JButton(FORWARDPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    navigationPanel.add(forwardPageButton);
    lastPageButton = new JButton(LASTPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT);
    navigationPanel.add(lastPageButton);

    // Get the container holding the components of this class
    Container con = getContentPane();

    // Set layout of this class
    con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    con.setLayout( new FlowLayout());

    // Add the fieldsPanel and buttonsPanel to this class.
    // con.add(menuBarPanel, BorderLayout);
    con.add(fieldsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    con.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    con.add(navigationPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //con.add(radioButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


    // Register listeners
    // ==================

    // Register action listeners on buttons
    saveButton.addActionListener(this);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);
    deleteButton.addActionListener(this);
    findButton.addActionListener(this);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    firstPageButton.addActionListener(this);
    backPageButton.addActionListener(this);
    forwardPageButton.addActionListener(this);
    lastPageButton.addActionListener(this);
    addPageButton.addActionListener(this);
    comicBookRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
    novelRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

    // Exit program when window is closed
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public void Radiobutton (){
     this.add(comicBookRadioButton);
     this.add(novelRadioButton);
     comicBookRadioButton.setSelected(true);
     this.setVisible(true);

}

// Populate the fields at the start of the application
public void populatefields(ComicBook cb) {
    String gradecode;

    // radio button selection = comic do this 
    if (cb != null) {

        upcTextField.setText(cb.getUpc());
        titleTextField.setText(cb.getTitle());
        issueNumTextField.setText(Integer.toString(cb.getIssuenumber()));
        writerTextField.setText(cb.getWriter());
        artistTextField.setText(cb.getArtist());
        publisherTextField.setText(cb.getPublisher());
        gradecode = cb.getGradeCode();
        gradeCodeTextField.setText(cb.determineCondition(gradecode));
        charactersTextField.setText(cb.getCharacters());
    }
    //radio button selection = novel do this 


    // Exit program when window is closed
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

/**
* 
*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    try {

        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals(COMICBOOK_BUTTON_TEXT)){
            //FormFictionCatelogue form = new FormFictionCatelogue();
            //form.populatefields(form.fc.returnObject(0));
            //ComicBookFields(fieldsPanel);
            populatefields(fc.returnComic(0));
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(NOVEL_BUTTON_TEXT)) {

        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(SAVE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            save();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(CLEAR_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            clear();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(ADDPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            add();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(DELETE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            delete();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(FIND_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            find();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(EXIT_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            exit();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(FIRSTPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            // first record
            populatefields(fc.firstRecord());
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(FORWARDPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            // next record
            populatefields(fc.nextRecord());
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(BACKPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            // previous record
            populatefields(fc.previousRecord());
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals(LASTPAGE_BUTTON_TEXT)) {
            // last record
            populatefields(fc.lastRecord());
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unknown event!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(), "Error!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

void clear() {
    upcTextField.setText("");
    titleTextField.setText("");
    issueNumTextField.setText("");
    writerTextField.setText("");
    artistTextField.setText("");
    gradeCodeTextField.setText("");
    publisherTextField.setText("");
    charactersTextField.setText("");
}

private void exit() {
    System.exit(0);
}

void add() {
    try{
    clear();
    ComicBook cb = new ComicBook();
    fc.add(cb);
    fc.lastRecord();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

void save() throws Exception {

    // if radio button = comic do this 
    ComicBook cb = new ComicBook();
    String condition;
    if (upcTextField.getText().length() == 16) {
        //searches if there is another record if()
        cb.setUpc(upcTextField.getText());
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Upc is not at required length ");
    }
    cb.setTitle(titleTextField.getText());
    cb.setIssuenumber(Integer.parseInt(issueNumTextField.getText()));
    cb.setWriter(writerTextField.getText());
    cb.setArtist(artistTextField.getText());
    cb.setPublisher(publisherTextField.getText());
    condition = cb.determineString(gradeCodeTextField.getText());
    if (condition.equals("Wrong Input")) {
        throw new Exception("Grade code is not valid");
    } else {
        cb.setGradeCode(condition);
    }
    cb.setCharacters(charactersTextField.getText());
    fc.save(cb);

    // if radio button = novels do this 
}

private void delete() throws Exception {
    fc.delete();
    populatefields(fc.getCurrentRecord());
}

private void find() {
    // from
    // http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/ShowInputDialog.shtml

    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter some text : ",
            "Comic Book Search", 1);
    if (str != null) {
        ComicBook cb = new ComicBook();
        cb = fc.search(str);
        if (cb != null) {
            populatefields(cb);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No comic books found ",
                    "Comic Book Search", 1);
        }

    }
}

public JPanel ComicBookFields(JPanel fieldsPanel) {
    // Create components and add to panels for ComicBook
    GridLayout fieldsPanelLayout = new GridLayout(9, 6);
    fieldsPanel.setLayout(fieldsPanelLayout);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("UPC: "));
    upcTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(upcTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Title: "));
    titleTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(titleTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Issue Number: "));
    issueNumTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(issueNumTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Writer: "));
    writerTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(writerTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Artist: "));
    artistTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(artistTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Publisher: "));
    publisherTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(publisherTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Grade Code: "));
    gradeCodeTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(gradeCodeTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Characters"));
    charactersTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(charactersTextField);

    return fieldsPanel;
}

public JPanel NovelFields(JPanel fieldsPanel) {
    // Create components and add to panels for ComicBook
    GridLayout fieldsPanelLayout = new GridLayout(9, 6);
    fieldsPanel.setLayout(fieldsPanelLayout);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("ISBN: "));
    isbnTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(isbnTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Title: "));
    titleTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(titleTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Book Number: "));
    bookNumTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(bookNumTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Author: "));
    authorTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(authorTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Publisher: "));
    publisherTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(publisherTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Series: "));
    seriesTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(seriesTextField);

    fieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Other Books"));
    otherBooksTextField = new JTextField(20);
    fieldsPanel.add(otherBooksTextField);

    return fieldsPanel;
}


}
```

Comment: Good read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It currently looks like this
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/yourphotos?pid=6016958174609950706&oid=111222071827801779938

Comment: 1. The majority of this code has nothing to with the question at hand. 2. You haven't stated the problem you are facing in reference to your question. 3. The answer to your only question _" Is there a way to when you press Novel to load the items from Novel to replace Comic book items?"_ is YES. If you want better help, try and post a better question, with an MCVE along with the problem your facing in regards the problem you're trying to tackle. Explain what you have tried (not just show code - where we have no idea where to look) and why it's giving you problems.

Answer (score 0):

To swap forms you can use a `CardLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

The example from the tutorial switches when you make a selection from a combo box. In your case you would change the panel when you click on the radio button. So you might also want to read the section from the tutorial on `How to Use Buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can switch `JPanel`s on `JRadioButton` selection like this:

You've got a `JPanel` called `displayPanel` which contains the `ComicPanel` by default, if you select the Novel `RadioButton` the `displayPanel` gets cleared and the `NovelPanel` will be added.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class AddNovelOrComicPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel selectPanel;
    private JPanel displayPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JRadioButton comic;
    private JRadioButton novel;

    // we need this ButtonGroup to take care about unselecting the former selected JRadioButton
    ButtonGroup radioButtons;

    public AddNovelOrComicPanel() {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
        this.add(selectPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all Components
     */
    private void initComponents() {

        selectPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        comic = new JRadioButton("Comic");
        comic.setSelected(true);
        comic.addActionListener(this);
        novel = new JRadioButton("Novel");
        novel.addActionListener(this);
        radioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
        radioButtons.add(comic);
        radioButtons.add(novel);
        selectPanel.add(comic);
        selectPanel.add(novel);

        displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.add(new ComicPanel());

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // if comic is selected show the ComicPanel in the displayPanel
        if(e.getSource().equals(comic)) {
            displayPanel.removeAll();
            displayPanel.add(new ComicPanel());

        }
        // if novel is selected show the NovelPanel in the displayPanel
        if(e.getSource().equals(novel)) {
            displayPanel.removeAll();
            displayPanel.add(new NovelPanel());
        }

        // revalidate all to show the changes
        revalidate();
    }

}

/**
 * The NovelPanel class
 * it contains all the Items you need to register a new Novel
 */
class NovelPanel extends JPanel {


    public NovelPanel() {
        this.add(new JLabel("Add your Novel components here"));
    }
}


/**
 * The ComicPanel class
 */
class ComicPanel extends JPanel {

    public ComicPanel() {
        this.add(new JLabel("Add your Comic components here"));
    }
}
```

So it is your choice what you want to do. Possible is nearly everything ;)

Patrick

Comment: Thanks a lot for that it helped a lot.
I just have an issue with populating fields not working now and unsure why would you have any clue?

Comment: Fine that i could help you solving your first problem. If it really helped you, accept this answer please as the correct answer, which helped. I would like to help you with your other problem too, but it is not the right way to ask within the comment to the current solution to your problem, because it is about another topic, so pls use the portal search if someone already solved it or aks a new question.